# How to disable automatic tab indentation change after copy paste?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tabs, indentation, copy-paste, auto-indent

When I copy a piece of code and paste it somewhere else in the IDE, my custom code indentation levels are changed by Visual Studio automatically. How do I prevent this?

Example:
[image]

My current tab settings are:
[image]

I want to continue using the Smart Indenting feature and actual tab characters (not spaces instead of them). I only want to prevent this particular behavior.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you are using Visual Assist X (a guess from the font highlighting), which does this. VS2012 itself doesn't have this feature so far as I know.

To turn it off in Visual Assist X, under VASSISTX->Visual Assist X Options..., select Advanced->Corrections and uncheck "Format after paste (in C/C++/C#/Javascript)".

[image]

Comment: Thought it was up to Visual Studio! Helped in a great.

Comment: Thank you! This also happens in **AtmelStudio** when that has VAssistX.  Another way to foil this execrable auto-formatting evil-feature is Ctrl-Z-**undo** once after pasting.